# how to call ArrayAdapter constructer from Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add a two-column ListView to my android app. When I created the project, I selected the option Fragment which creates that beautiful navigation by sliding to left and right. So my `MainActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

my problem is when I am trying to add AddayAdapter to ListView, the construstor of ArrayAdapter looks for a context object and I dont know to pass that.

here is the code where I get error

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row , list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I pass "this", it passes FragmentActivity because the activity extends FragmentActivity. but constructor need a "Context" object.

it gives this error message

```
"The constructor MainActivity.StableArrayAdapter(MainActivity.DummySectionFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined"
```

How can I pass Context object?

Comment: try this: StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row , list);

Comment: `FragmentActivity.this` instead of `this`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the adapter inside a fragment. Use

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.row , list);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row , list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Did you try passing something like this from your Fragment. Try either `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I cannot see it popups in intellisense, that means it cannot reach them

Comment: this is not working, did you try passing yourActivity.this or getActivity(), let me know if this works.